# Problem with ktor client in Intellij Idea plugin development?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-plugin, ktor

I am developing a plugin for IntelliJ Idea
I want to use Ktor Client to use `websocket` feature

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(WebSockets)
}
```

when I send a websocket request

```kotlin
client.webSocket(...)
```

this exception will be thrown

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()' the class loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @a02df19 of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader @2ac1fdc4 for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature (org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @a02df19, parent loader 'bootstrap'; org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader @2ac1fdc4)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:423)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
    at io.ktor.util.logging.KtorSimpleLoggerJvmKt.KtorSimpleLogger(KtorSimpleLoggerJvm.kt:10)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSocketsKt.<clinit>(WebSockets.kt:22)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSockets$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(WebSockets.kt:162)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSockets$Plugin$install$1.invoke(WebSockets.kt)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSockets$Plugin$install$1.invoke(WebSockets.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceedWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:88)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:126)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invoke(HttpCallValidator.kt)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invoke(HttpCallValidator.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt:35)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invoke(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invoke(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute$ktor_utils(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:98)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:77)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.execute$ktor_client_core(HttpClient.kt:191)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.executeUnsafe(HttpStatement.kt:108)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket(builders.kt:243)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket(builders.kt:119)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket(builders.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket$default(builders.kt:132)
    at ir.amirab.debugboard.ideaplugin.Backend$initiateWebsocket$1.invokeSuspend(Backend.kt:70)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSocketsKt
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSockets$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(WebSockets.kt:162)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSockets$Plugin$install$1.invoke(WebSockets.kt)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.WebSockets$Plugin$install$1.invoke(WebSockets.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceedWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:88)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpCallValidator.kt:126)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invoke(HttpCallValidator.kt)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpCallValidator$Companion$install$1.invoke(HttpCallValidator.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invokeSuspend(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt:35)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invoke(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpRequestLifecycle$Plugin$install$1.invoke(HttpRequestLifecycle.kt)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:120)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:78)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute$ktor_utils(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:98)
    at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:77)
    at io.ktor.client.HttpClient.execute$ktor_client_core(HttpClient.kt:191)
    at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.executeUnsafe(HttpStatement.kt:108)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket(builders.kt:243)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket(builders.kt:119)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket(builders.kt:137)
    at io.ktor.client.plugins.websocket.BuildersKt.webSocket$default(builders.kt:132)
    at ir.amirab.debugboard.ideaplugin.Backend$initiateWebsocket$1.invokeSuspend(Backend.kt:70)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

I also test ktor server. it also give me same Exception!
My question is

- Is it valid to use `ktor` in idea plugins?
- If thats ok then what I have to do to fix this?

I used these versions

```
kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
ideaPluginVersion = "1.13.1"
ktorVersion = "2.2.2"
```

here is my full build.gradle.kts

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.8.0"
    id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.13.1"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// Configure Gradle IntelliJ Plugin
// Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html
intellij {
    version.set("2022.1.4")
    type.set("IC") // Target IDE Platform

    plugins.set(listOf(/* Plugin Dependencies */))
}


dependencies {
    val ktorVersion = "2.2.2"
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:$ktorVersion")
}

tasks {
    // Set the JVM compatibility versions
    withType<JavaCompile> {
        sourceCompatibility = "11"
        targetCompatibility = "11"
    }
    withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    patchPluginXml {
        sinceBuild.set("221")
        untilBuild.set("231.*")
    }

    signPlugin {
        certificateChain.set(System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_CHAIN"))
        privateKey.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
        password.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD"))
    }

    publishPlugin {
        token.set(System.getenv("PUBLISH_TOKEN"))
    }
}
```

###### UPDATE:

it seems when I add ktor dependencies

```
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()
```

this code will throw that exception even if I don't use ktor at all!

##### UPDATE:

I temporary add this

```kotlin
configurations.all { 
    exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api")
}
```

to build.gradle.kts and fixed my problem but I don't know is it practical but at least works!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is possible to use the ktor client in idea plugins.

I was able to run the ktor client websocket inside the plugin without any problems and it read and logged incoming messages here is my code:

```kotlin
val ktorClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(WebSockets)
}

class PluginAction : DumbAwareAction() {

    override fun actionPerformed(event: AnActionEvent) {

        CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            ktorClient.webSocket(
                method = HttpMethod.Get,
                host = "localhost",
                path = "/path",
            ) {
                while (true) {
                    val incoming = (incoming.receive() as Frame.Text).readText()
                    thisLogger().info("incoming: $incoming")
                }
            }
        }
        ktorClient.close()
    }
}
```

build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
val ktorVersion = "2.2.2"

dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-websockets:$ktorVersion")
}
```

Judging by your log `io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentBuilder`, you tried to use the ktor server module
which crashed due to missing settings.

Based on your question, you need exactly the client.

also you missed the engine, i used СIO

`val ktorClient = HttpClient(CIO) {...}`

See also:

[Setup ktor websocket client](https://ktor.io/docs/websocket-client.html)

[Client webSockets code example](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/tree/2.2.3/codeSnippets/snippets/client-websockets)

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was testing ktor server too . and it was similar to client exception either. I edited that . can you please check it again?

Comment: can you please add your build.gradle to question?

Comment: Sure. I added build.gradle.kts

Comment: please try to change the ktor version to val ktorVersion = "2.0.1"
I'm not ready to paint the reasons yet, but I think it will help

Comment: I did that .it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe its because of gradle version that I am using? can you give me your gradle version ? I am totally confused! I also tested on a fresh intelij idea template but it have same problem too!

Comment: i use 7.4.2 https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
my example in github: https://github.com/Corexis/demo1

Comment: using this example i also tried your versions of kotlin and
ideaPlugin

Comment: I build and ran your demo. but this exception thrown when I pressed "greeting/hello action"  : on Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandlerImplKt

Comment: its really strange, https://i.imgur.com/2B5BEB3.png proof that it works for me. I will try to look for reasons and answer why this happens, but until then this answer will be useless. I will leave it to leave available the history of our attempts. I sincerely apologize for not being able to help quickly.

Comment: Thats OK thanks. I found a temporary solution and added to question

Answer (score 0):

same issue, gradle config below

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.21")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-jvm:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-auth:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.0")
}
```

and fixed by

```
configurations.all {
    exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api")
}
```